# adding multiple textfields to a single focus listener

Tags: java, actionlistener

i am trying to add multiple text fields in to a single focus listener to be executed, currently i have added a text field but i cant figure out how to add multiple text fields to it,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i think its way better than creating a focus listener for each textfield.

Usually tha anser is: "it depends..."

but in your case Id say: each textfield should have its own listener (instance). 
The reason is that you change the textfields content.
When you do this in only one Listener instance then you either change all the textfields any time the event occurs regarless of which textfield was affected, or you end up with a `if`/`else` cascade needing a new entry if you add another textfield.

I suggest that you create a named inner class for the Listener giving it a Textfield as parameter:

```
class MyTextFiledFocusListener implements FocusListener {
  private final JTextFiled textField;
  MyTextFiledFocusListener(JTextFiled textField){
    this.textField = textField;
    textField.addFocusListener(this);
  }
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) 
  {
    textField.setText("");
  }

  public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
  {
    // nothing
  }
}
```

and the bit you posted changes to:

```
new MyTextFiledFocusListener(JT_id);
```

---

Just for the records:

quite a lot Swing related interfaces with more than one method have default implementations with empty methods (the pre java8 solution for *default methods*) so does  `FocusListener`. These default implementation are usually called `*Adapter`. Therefore you could shorten your code when you extend [FocusAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusAdapter.html) insted of implementing  `FocusListener`:

```
class MyTextFiledFocusListener extends FocusAdapter {
  private final JTextFiled textField;
  MyTextFiledFocusListener(JTextFiled textField){
    this.textField = textField;
    textField.addFocusListener(this);
  }
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) 
  {
    textField.setText("");
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir, Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
FocusListener clearFields = new FocusListener() {
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) 
{
   JT_id.setText("");
   JT_name.setText("");
   JT_add.setText("");
   JT_cno.setText("");
   JT_email.setText("");
}

public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
{
  // nothing
}
});

JT_id.addFocusListener(clearFields);
JT_name.addFocusListener(clearFields);
JT_add.addFocusListener(clearFields);
JT_cno.addFocusListener(clearFields);
JT_email.addFocusListener(clearFields)
```

You will still need to add a focus listener to all of the text-fields to avoid the situation where clicking/focusing on the first one (`JT_id`) will clear all of them while clicking/focusing on the others would do nothing.

Or, you know, the alternative - assign each textfield a focuslistener that only clears that field.

Comment: sir, is there no way that only clear specific field,without adding focuslistener for every textfield?

Comment: unfortunatelly no. or wait, i understood that you want to clear the field you clicked on (the field that gained focus), if that's not the case please leave a comment and update your question please. otherwise the "unfortuantelly no" comment applies.